# JQuery loop to display every six items into an new unordered list

Tags: jquery, json

I'm a bit new to the jquery world and I was wondering: I have a JSON object that returns content from a database. How would I loop through those items to display only six per ul with each item being appended within that ul in a li, then construct a new ul every six items to display the remaining items in a li? Basically I'm trying to to this:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4
- item 5
- item 6

- item 7
- item 8
- item 9
- item 10
- item 11
- item 12

etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
function buildLists(data, element) {

    var count = parseInt((data.length / 6) + (data.length % 6 == 0 ? 0 : 1), 10),
        html = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        html += "<ul>";
        for (var j = i; j < (6 + (6 * i)); j++) {
            html += "<li>" + data[j] + "</li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
    }

    element.append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be mostly core JavaScript.

```
    $(function() { //execute when DOM is ready
    var lists = '<ul>'; //start off list
    var nums = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'); //add a few items to an array for demo

    var i = 1; //1-based count for "every six"
    var j = 0; //0-based count for array keys
    while (i <= nums.length){
       if(i%6 == 0){ //check if number is a multiple of 6
           if(i != nums.length){ 
            lists += '<li>'+nums[j]+'</li></ul><ul>';  
           }else{ //if this is the last array value, don't start a new ul
               lists += '<li>'+nums[j]+'</li></ul>';  
           }
       }else {
           lists += '<li>'+nums[j]+'</li>';   
       }
       i++; //go to next number
       j++; //go to next number
   }


      $('body').append(lists); //ad uls to page
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses an array, but should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(i % 6 == 0 && i > 0) {    
    console.log(ul.html()); // change this line - insert into the DOM wherever you'd like
    ul = $("<ul></ul>");
  }
  ul.append("<li>" + i + "</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution using jQuery's ".each" function. The core code to do the loop and list creation is pretty small. Note: this is assuming the return JSON object has nested data.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var data = 
    [
        {value: 1},{value: 2},{value: 3},{value: 4},{value: 5},{value: 6},
        {value: 7},{value: 8},{value: 9},{value: 10},{value: 11},{value: 12},
        {value: 13},{value: 14},{value: 15},{value: 16},{value: 17},{value: 18}
    ];

    var $listReference;
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        if(i == 0 || (i) % 6 == 0){
            $listReference = $("<ul>");
            $("body").append($listReference);
        }
        $listReference.append($("<li>").text(item.value));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend practicing [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). One of the key principles is separating markup from design; you want to break the view into blocks of 6, but the data your representing is still a long, continuous, list. If you create multiple lists to represent this, it would be misleading to any scripts trying to make sense of the content on your page, or specialised clients like screenreaders.

Thus, I would create a single list, and use CSS to make it appear as multiple blocks.

CSS:

```
  .newBlock { margin-top: 1em; }
```

Javascript:

```
var records = 
[ {name: "a"},{name: "b"},{name: "c"},{name: "d"},{name: "e"},{name: "f"},
  {name: "g"},{name: "h"},{name: "i"},{name: "j"},{name: "k"},{name: "l"},
  {name: "m"},{name: "n"},{name: "o"},{name: "p"},{name: "q"},{name: "r"}
]; // sample data, adapted from WesleyJohnson's example
var $ul = $("<ul/>").appendTo("body");
$.each(records, function(count, record) {
  var $li = $("<li/>").html(record.name).appendTo($ul);
  if (count % 6 == 0) $li.addClass("newBlock");
});
```

[online demo](http://jsbin.com/abubi)

Comment: Hello mahemoff!  I tried out your solution and came REALLY close but for some reason, it only displays the first item of the six only which is strange.  It's a bit modified from your original code but the same structure.  Is there any way I can send you what I have?

Comment: Should work - did you see the linked demo btw? I'd try getting rid of the CSS and you should just see the long list.

You can send it to michael@mahemoff.com or put it on a pastebin and link here, thanks.